# Angular 2 - Child route have a different parent component to parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi I've got my routes file set up like this

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: parentComponent, canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ], children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
        { path: 'sign-out', component: SignOutComponent },
        { path: 'set-password', component: SetPasswordComponent },
        { path: '', canActivate: [ LastLoginDateGuard ], children: [
            { path: 'admin', canActivate: [ adminGuard ], children: [
                { path: 'event/:event_id',  component: appComponent,  children: [
                    { path: '', component: EventComponent }
                ]},
            ]},
        ]},
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]},
    { path: '', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
    { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

What I need is for the `event/:event_id` route to have a different parent component to the normal `parentComponent`

```js
{ path: 'admin', canActivate: [ adminGuard ], children: [
  { path: 'event/:event_id',  component: appComponent,  children: [
    { path: '', component: EventComponent }
  ]},
]},
```

I basically just want the parent component of `event/:event_id` to be `appComponent` not the `parentCompnent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to remove whole route part from `ParentComponent` child and make another with parent of `AppComponent`,

Please try this route setting :

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: parentComponent, canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ], children: [
        { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
        { path: 'sign-out', component: SignOutComponent },
        { path: 'set-password', component: SetPasswordComponent },
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' }

    ]},

    { path: '', canActivate: [ LoggedInGuard ], children: [
        { path: '', canActivate: [ LastLoginDateGuard ], children: [
            { path: 'admin', component: appComponent, canActivate: [ adminGuard ], children: [
                { path: 'event/:event_id' ,  children: [
                    { path: '', component: EventComponent }
                ]},
            ]},
        ]}
    ]},

    { path: '', component: AppComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'sign-in', component: SignInComponent },
    { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: I was thinking I could do it that way just making my routes file bigger

Comment: @SCRATK, then you can use lazyloading and separate the routes files.